# Shortest way to create a date

Tags: haskell

I am building a date in a specific format starting from year, month and day available:

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format

getDate :: Text -> Text -> Text -> String
getDate year month day = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%B %d %Y" date
                         where date = buildTime defaultTimeLocale oldDate :: UTCTime
                               oldDate = zip "Ymd" $ map unpack [year, month, day]
```

Anyway what I am doing here it looks too long (before I put values in a format and then convert that format in another format). Is there a way to make only one single conversion? I look through the API but I am not sure there is something like that available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your code is quite clean and you don't need to worry. But if you are still interested this is somewhat shorter than your code:

```
import Data.Time.Format
import Data.Text (Text, unpack, pack)
import Data.Time.Calendar

getDate :: Text -> Text -> Text -> String
getDate year month day = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%B %d %Y" (fromGregorian (toInt year) (toInt month) (toInt day)) 
    where
      toInt :: (Read a, Num a) => Text -> a
      toInt = read . unpack
```

Or if you can change the interface slightly then it can be even more short:

```
getDate2 :: Integer -> Int -> Int -> String
getDate2 year month day = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%B %d %Y" (fromGregorian year month day)
```